# underscore template cannot access variable

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have a structure that looks like this:

```
var results = (
    0: array(1,2,3),
    1: array(2,3,4)
)
```

I'd like to use underscore.js templating to put both `result [0]` and `result [1]` in a table like this

```
<table id="results">
   <tr>
      <td>
         1
      </td>
      <td>
         2
      </td>
      <td>
         3
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
         2
      </td>
      <td>
         3 
      </td>
      <td>
         4
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

using

```
var list = "<% _.each(results, function(val) { %> <tr><% val.forEach(function(val1){ %> <td><%= val1 %></td>  <% }); %></tr> <% }); %>";
console.log(_.template(list, results));
```

I'm getting the error that `results is not defined` however. Even though if when I pause the debugger right before the underscore code and check out the value of results, I can see my array of arrays. What's going wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Underscore doesn't know that your variable is called results, you need to pass it an object of your variables like so:

```
_.template(list, { results: results });
```

Comment: thanks. but now I get ` Object 1 has no method 'forEach'` Can I get back that functionality somehow?

Comment: So does your `results` variable look like `[[1,2,3],[2,3,4]]`? Because this works for me.